# What is different this return of promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

What is different promise here

```
promise()
.then(
   otherPromise()
)
.catch(error)
```

and here :

```
promise()
.then(() => {
   otherPromise()
})
.catch(error)
```

Someone can help me with explain it

Comment: Please read a javascript tutorial, e.g. https://javascript.info.

Comment: In one you're (presumably) passing a promise _as a callback_, in the other it's just not part of the outer chain.

Comment: In the first the _result_ of `otherPromise()` method call is passed as the callback to `then` in the second, `otherPromise()` is executed as the callback.

Comment: And they are both incorrect if you expect it to wait for the otherPromise

Comment: *"Someone can help me with explain it"* No, we can't, not without knowing what `promise` and `otherPromise` are. They clearly aren't promises, because you're *calling* them, and promises aren't callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're passing the return value of calling `otherPromise()` to your `then`. In the second example you're passing a function which will call `otherPromise()` when the `then` is reached.

For example, lets assume `otherPromise()` just returns a string like this:

```js
const otherPromise = () => 'Hello World';
```

In the first example you are passing the string 'Hello World' into your then, in the second you are passing a function in.

I suspect what you want to do is this:

```js
promise()
  .then(otherPromise)
  .catch(error)
```